# Boost IPC Equivalent (qt?)

Tags: c++, qt, boost, ipc

I am working on an application which currently has a plugin to a particular software suite and then a separate application which communicates with the plugin using boost ipc.

The latest version of the application we are plugging into was just released with a very old version of boost (1.35 I think) as part of their SDK. The previous developer who worked on actually integrating ipc (and has since moved jobs) has told us that we really do need to be at boost 1.46 for this to work.

If there is any way for us to keep on using boost 1.46 and working around their inclusion of the old boost, that would be great, but my understanding is that that is not possible.

As such, what other equivalent packages are there that can easily enable cross-application communication? We previously just used qt's signals and slots, but moved away from that in favor of ipc (no one can particularly remember why that was done of course...)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Liron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using XML and TCP/IP? It is future proof and independent from the OS and the implementation.

Check [QTcpServer](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qtcpserver.html), [QTcpSocket](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qtcpsocket.html), [QXmlStreamReader](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qxmlstreamreader.html) and [QXmlStreamWriter](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qxmlstreamwriter.html)!

For classical IPC: [check Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/ipc.html).

Comment: So of course, the application I'm building against is using Qt compiled against VS2008, (which is a requirement for any plugins if they want to use Qt), but we have a separate requirement to use VS 2005. Fortunately, the plugin sdk has a TCPIP implementation as part of it, so hopefully that implementation plays well with Qt, as I"m going to use that on the standalone application that connects to the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly you are implementing, you may want to look at the [Qxt library](http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/wiki/Home) for Qt, particularly their [IPC classes](http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/0.6/tech-ipc.html).